# Equally Distributing MTLTexture inside Triangle

Tags: swift, metal, metalkit

I want to add texture to the below diagram[image: Vertex Distribution]

I want to add texture between four equally distributed.my texture is square size. since Vertex 0,1,2,3 are not square I cannot place it equally distributed.

Other question is how many square textures maximumly we can add to this diagram ?

I currently doing it by below in the shader it is not equally distributing and maximum i can add 3 textures

```
    if(vertexId == 0){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,0);
    }
    else if(vertexId == 1){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,1);
    }
    else if(vertexId == 2){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(1,0);
    }
//
    else if(vertexId == 3){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(1,1);
    }


    else if(vertexId == 4){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,0);
    }
    else if(vertexId == 5){
        vo.textureCoordinates = float2(0,1);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "equally distributed"? Can you show a picture of what you want vs. what you're getting?

Comment: If we add square texture to parallelogram not a square one it will distort I want to add equally distributed. I add an image https://imgur.com/VWHPFVm

Comment: https://imgur.com/W3r61zf This image shows the issue. input Texture is https://imgur.com/U59OIeu